# Replace c:\ with file:\\\c| using PHP

Tags: php

I have the local file path as c:\new folder\pdf\today\k.pdf  I want to replace the c:\ with file:\\c|

I tried `str_replace('','',)` but I get error due to the slash, no stripslash will not work.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$string = 'c:\new folder\pdf\hello.pdf';
$new_str = str_replace("c:\\", "file:\\\\\\c|", $string);
echo $new_str;
```

**Result:**

```
file:\\\c|new folder\pdf\hello.pdf
```

Comment: I want to replace the c:\ with file:\\\c|

Comment: My current path is c:\new folder\pdf\hello.pdf
I want to change it to file:\\\c|

I used striplashes to remove all "\\"

Comment: more over the "\" in $string = 'c:\'; will flag an error as shown above its all red after the 'c:\';

Answer (score 2):

Isn't `c:\new folder\pdf\today\k.pdf` to `file:///c|new folder/pdf/today/k.pdf`?

If so, following will work, without regex

```
$x='c:\new folder\pdf\today\k.pdf';

$x='file:///'.str_replace('\\','/',str_replace(':\\','|',$x));
```

`file:///c|new folder/pdf/today/k.pdf` will return

Comment: This is the usual format for `file:` URLs. file-double-backslash doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<?php
$a = 'c:\new folder\pdf\today\k.pdf';

$a = str_replace('c:\\','file:\\\\\\c|',$a);

var_dump($a); // print string(36) "file:\\\c|new folder\pdf\today\k.pdf"

?>
```